# Different div tags using regular expression in php

Tags: php

In html form:

```
<div class="student_information">
        <tr>
           <div class="admin"><td>141201A</td></div>
            <div class="name"><td>Sally</td></div>
            <div class="hp"><td>83556112</td></div>
            <div class="email"><td>141201A@gmail.com</td></div>
        </tr>
```

```
Output I wanted: 
141201A
Sally Tan
83556112
141201A@gmail.com
```

I want to get the content between div and td. I do understand that there are other choices like xpath and DOM Document which would be more suitable however my project required us to use regular expression in php otherwise it will affect the later part of the project thus any helps is required. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to match  the case where you have content directly inside a div without td , for example : ``<div>my content</div>`` ?

Comment: I need my content without the <div> </div>

Comment: So even in this case(my example) you still need to match the content of that div ?

Comment: In this case(ur example) I still need to match the content of that div

Comment: A ``div`` tag as a direct child of a ``tr`` tag is not a valid HTML5 Code, instead you can put your div inside a td tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
<?php
$str = '<div class="student_information">
        <tr>
           <div class="admin"><td>141201A</td></div>
            <div class="name"><td>Sally</td></div>
            <div class="hp"><td>83556112</td></div>
            <div class="email"><td>141201A@gmail.com</td></div>
        </tr>';
$content = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $str);
$content = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $content)));
$arr = explode(' ', $content);
if (! empty($arr)) {
 foreach ($arr as $elem) {
  echo $elem . "<br/>";
 }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
141201A
Sally
83556112
141201A@gmail.com
```

Comment: Do u have any ways to load the $str (html) from database in php form?

Answer (score 0):

Use php [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
<?php
$str = '<div class="student_information">
        <tr>
           <div class="admin"><td>141201A</td></div>
            <div class="name"><td>Sally</td></div>
            <div class="hp"><td>83556112</td></div>
            <div class="email"><td>141201A@gmail.com</td></div>
        </tr>';
$strpped = strip_tags ($str);
$strpped = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $strpped)));
echo $strpped;
?>
```

Output:

```
141201A
Sally
83556112
141201A@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the help however I need to use regular expression(regex) to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

To remove html tags use [php strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) (as it uses regex) like this:

```
<?php
$str = '<div class="student_information">
        <tr>
            <div class="admin"><td>141201A</td></div>
            <div class="name"><td>Sally</td></div>
            <div class="hp"><td>83556112</td></div>
            <div class="email"><td>141201A@gmail.com</td></div>
        </tr>';
preg_match_all('/<td>[a-zA-Z0-9.@]+<\/td>/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 141201A
    [1] => Sally
    [2] => 83556112
    [3] => 141201A@gmail.com
)
```