# How to remove <tags> using regex in php

Tags: php, regex, tags

I need to remove the div and td tags in order to extract out the content between  to insert into database. However to some constraints I have to use regex and not xpath or DOM Document to extract out the content. Need help! Thanks

```
 <tr class = "student_information" >
            <div class="admin"><td>141234U</td></div>
            <div class="name"><td>Tan Ping Ping</td></div>
            <div class="hp"><td>82222222</td></div>
            <div class="email"><td>141234U@mymail.nyp.edu.sg</td></div>
        </tr>
                    <tr class = "student_information" >
            <div class="admin"><td>132458Q</td></div>
            <div class="name"><td>Tan Rui</td></div>
            <div class="hp"><td>86339557</td></div>
            <div class="email"><td>132458Q@hotmail.com</td></div>

 Output: 

 141234U
 Tan Ping Ping
 82222222
 141234U@mymail.nyp.edu.sg

 132458Q
 Tan Rui
 86339557
 132458Q@hotmail.com
```

Comment: **"I have to use regex and not xpath or DOM Document to extract out the content"**, homework ?

Comment: I tried using $pattern =  /<div class.*><td>(.*)<\/td><\/div>/  and $pattern = #<td.*>(.*)</td>#

Comment: Having school project

Comment: What happened with that regex you presented? Seems to work here, https://regex101.com/r/qU6qJ7/1. If you are using `s` modifier make that `.*` non-greedy with `?` I'd recommend posting what you've tried so we are re-inventing things here..

Comment: Sorry cause i am still new here. I will post more of what i have tried.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has already been asked twice, both questions with accepted answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136781/regex-with-div-classes
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130517/different-div-tags-using-regular-expression-in-php

Answer (score 0):

> However to some constraints I have to use regex and not xpath or DOM
>   Document to extract out the content

Based on the above, you can use this regex: `(?<=>)([\w .@]+)(?=<)`, i.e.:

```
$str = <<< EOF
 <tr class = "student_information" >
            <div class="admin"><td>141234U</td></div>
            <div class="name"><td>Tan Ping Ping</td></div>
            <div class="hp"><td>82222222</td></div>
            <div class="email"><td>141234U@mymail.nyp.edu.sg</td></div>
        </tr>
                    <tr class = "student_information" >
            <div class="admin"><td>132458Q</td></div>
            <div class="name"><td>Tan Rui</td></div>
            <div class="hp"><td>86339557</td></div>
            <div class="email"><td>132458Q@hotmail.com</td></div>
EOF;

preg_match_all('/(?<=>)([\w .@]+)(?=<)/', $str, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
foreach($result[1] as $match){
echo $match."\n";
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
141234U
Tan Ping Ping
82222222
141234U@mymail.nyp.edu.sg
132458Q
Tan Rui
86339557
132458Q@hotmail.com
```

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
(?<=>)([\w.@]+)(?=<)

Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=>)»
   Match the character “>” literally «>»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([\w.@]+)»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[\w.@]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, any number, underscore) «\w»
      A single character from the list “.@” «.@»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=<)»
   Match the character “<” literally «<»
```

Comment: That is the html string from another database, how do i use it in this ?

Comment: if ($matchcount > 0) {
       
        for($i = 0; $i < $matchcount; $i++) {
        echo("\nMatch #" . ($i + 1) . ":\n");
        echo($matches[1][$i]); // print 1st capture group for match number i

      
  

       } else {
        echo('No matches');
       }